# Capture full output of command in batch file (only capture first character)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have to create a batch file where I check the status of my service thanks to [nssm](https://nssm.cc/). The command that I use is `nssm status MyService` and it returns `SERVICE_STOPPED` OR `SERVICE_RUNNING`. I do not have a lot of experience with batch file so I followed some SO answers to achieve what I want, here is my file :

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('nssm status MyService') DO (
SET var=%%F
)
ECHO %var%
```

But when I echo the output I only get the first character of the expected output.

var is equal to `S`

I tried to change tokens and delims parameters but without success it always returns `S`

What did I missed ? Is it the FOR /F parameters ? Or how I set my variable ?

Comment: If all that command does is output `SERVICE_STOPPED` or `SERVICE_RUNNING` there is no way the code you are using would truncate the output.

Comment: NSSM could be Unicode. Why are you not using Windows commands. NSSM is not a Service Control program, even if it can do that as well. See `for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=," %A in (`wmic service where "name='rpcss'" get state /format:csv`) Do echo %A`

Comment: @Squashman When I run `nssm status MyService` in the command-line it returns `SERVICE_RUNNING`, is it possible to have different output between the command-line and running in a batch file ?

Comment: @CatCat I use NSSM to run batch file as service so it restart when it crash, the code that you gave me always return me `RUNNING`

Comment: Rpcss IS ALWAYS RUNNING. Else everything will crash.

Comment: What happens when you use the `SC` command to query the status of the service?

Comment: @Squashman this works with `SC`, this might be a problem with the output of NSSM command, I put my final code in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved that, the problem might come with NSSM command line, instead I used `SC` command to query my service as mentionned @Squashman

```
set list=service1 service2
for %%a in (%list%) do (
  FOR /F "tokens=4" %%F IN ('sc query %%a ^| find "STATE     "') DO (
    IF %%F NEQ RUNNING (
      nssm start %%a
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=," %A in (`wmic service where "name='rpcss'" get state /format:csv`) Do echo %A
```